# How to query items in array alone in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My collection name is employee and my collections as follows

```
{
   "Title":"IssueFixingTeam",
   "TeamLead":"Mr.Bean",
   "workers":["xxx","yyy","zzz"]
 },

{
   "Title":"DevelopmentTeam",
   "TeamLead":"Mr.John Doe",
   "workers":["aa","dd","ss"]
 }
```

how to query to find, how many workers are there under TeamLead "Mr.Bean"
Thanks in advance

Comment: share us what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are interested in just one record (otherwise, see the answer by @felix) belonging to "Mr.Bean", then this could give you the required count:

```
db.employee.findOne({'TeamLead': 'Mr.Bean'}).workers.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Match

```
   to filter TeamLead: Mr.Bean
```

use Size operator in Project

```
   to get size of array,



    db.collection.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            TeamLead: "Mr.Bean"
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "TeamLead":1,
            workers: {
                $size: "$workers"
            }
        }
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

In case you are only interested in matching documents of a specific `TeamLead` and sum **per document**:

```
db.foo.aggregate([{$match: {"TeamLead": "Mr.Bean"}},
                  {$project: {"num_workers": {$size: "$workers"}}}])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c6a5ef9bc86fa5c7e4fa50"), "num_workers" : 3 }
```

---

If you want to group documents by `TeamLead` and get the number of unique workers under each `TeamLead`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([{$group: {"_id": "$TeamLead", "workers": {$addToSet: "$workers"}}},
                  {$unwind: "$workers"},
                  {$project: {"num_workers": {$size: "$workers"}}}])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "Mr.John Doe", "num_workers" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Mr.Bean", "num_workers" : 3 }
```